# Read 2D matrix csv file into QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, 2d

I have a big spatial dataset file that I need to import to the QGIS to get the temperature data from each grid. However, the dataset file is in the format of having longitude as first row, latitude as first column. And the temperature data is in the format of a 2D matrix.

Is there a way to read the file to the QGIS? Or is there an easier way to convert the file to QGIS-readable format? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import this into QGIS as a point shapefile, you need each unique point to be its own row in the spreadsheet.

So you should convert this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

With n different latitudes and longitudes, your end result has n-squared lines. (In my example, n=5 so there are 25 lines in the second sheet.) Then you import the new spreadsheet and each line of the new spreadsheet becomes a point in QGIS. In my example, the original 2-D table is Sheet1 and the 1-D table is Sheet2 in the same Excel workbook. In the next image, I've removed the equals sign from each cell formula so you can see the formulas I used.

[image]

EDIT: It probably makes more sense to display this information in raster format. Use the rasterize tool to convert from a vector to a raster.

[image]

Comment: If you convert your data into XYZ, you can use ASCII GRIDDED XYZ raster format to read points into a grid in one step inQGIS (be carefull the order of points, increasing Y order)

Comment: I used R to convert the data into XYZ, now it works! Thanks @Zoltan and csk

Answer (score 3):

If this single file have to be converted to QGIS, change it manually into an ESRI ASCII GRID. Remove the first row and the first column in libre/open office calc, save as data into a csv file. The separator should be space in the grid file (extension .grd). Add manually the header information to the file:

```
ncols 180
nrows 90
xllcorner -179 
yllcorner -89
cellsize 2
nodata_value -9999
0.20 0.20 0.20 ....
...
```

I hope I guess the number of columns and rows well.
Open this file as a raster (Arc/info ASCII GRID) in QGIS.

Comment: Zoltan, many thanks. Would you mind teaching me how to manually add the header information to the file?

Comment: I have created a raster like this

Comment: This is a raster that I made: https://flic.kr/p/MYKdB2

Comment: I used your suggested method. but the raster is repeating itself in QGIS

Comment: You need a simple text editor to add header. Please let me see your spreadsheet and grid files, without that I can't help.

Comment: thanks much. Really helped me. Worked for QGIS and SAGA - set extension to *.asc. Used LibreOffice Calc and PSPad.